# Printing from WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, printdialog

I have a WPF data entry screen/windowthat I want to provide a print-out for.  (To be precise, it's a UserControl I've rigged up to work as as a TabItem in a TabControl that I want to print.)

To print nicely, I make a couple of layout transforms, scale the window to the paper size, and change the skin of the application. The 'print skin' changes the background to white, and removes backgrounds on header labels, etc.

This worked perfectly - while I had `MessageBox.Show()` prompts telling me what was happening.

However, when I took out the Messagebox.Show prompts, I found all my printing magic didn't work, and it was as if the enire printing method was just: `PrintVisual();` on the UserControl. (I have narrowed this down to the one MessageBox that I can't get rid of without breaking things.)

The code (sorry it's so long, I've added bulk comments):

```
private void PrintStatements()
{
  PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();

  /// Needed data
  PrintCapabilities capabilities = print.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(print.PrintTicket);
  double pageMargin = 1 / 2.54;   // 1cm
  double pageWidth = capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth - (pageMargin);
  double pageLength = capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight - (pageMargin);
  Size pageSize = new Size(pageWidth, pageLength);
  ResourceDictionary resources = new ResourceDictionary();

  bool canPrint = print.ShowDialog() ?? false;
  if (canPrint)
  {
    double tabWidth = StatementsTabCtrl.ActualWidth;
    double tabHeight = StatementsTabCtrl.ActualHeight;

    /// 1.  Get tab item content ('currentTabContent') 
    StatementsTabItem currentTabContent = StatementsTabCtrl.SelectedContent as StatementsTabItem;

    /// 2.  Get Original Specs of currentTabContent
    ResourceDictionary origSkin = Application.Current.Resources;
    Size origSize = new Size(currentTabContent.ActualWidth, currentTabContent.ActualHeight);
    Transform origTransform = currentTabContent.LayoutTransform;

    /// 3.  Transform currentTabContent (expose print panels, move stuff around etc) - 
        //do this inside TabItem class
    currentTabContent.SetupPrinting();

    /// 4.  Make changes outside TabItem (skin, page-scale)
        // skin
    resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(@"Skin/PrintDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary);
    Application.Current.Resources = resources;
        // page-scale
    double scale = Math.Min(pageWidth / currentTabContent.ActualWidth,
                            pageLength / currentTabContent.ActualHeight);

    // ****Uncomment next line - printing magic works.**** //
    // MessageBox.Show(string.Format("scaling by {0}", scale));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);

    currentTabContent.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

    //Measure and Arrange
    currentTabContent.Measure(pageSize);
    ((UIElement)currentTabContent).Arrange(new Rect(
         new Point((capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth + pageMargin),
             (capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight + pageMargin)), pageSize));

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);

    /// 5. Print (Finally!)
    print.PrintVisual(currentTabContent, "Print Results");

    /// 6. Return everything to normal (undo 3, then 4)
        // undo 3.
    currentTabContent.TearDownPrinting();
        // undo 4.
    Application.Current.Resources = origSkin;
    scale = Math.Max(currentTabContent.ActualWidth / pageWidth,
                                    currentTabContent.ActualHeight / pageLength);
    currentTabContent.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(1 / scale, 1 / scale);

    currentTabContent.Measure(origSize);
    ((UIElement)currentTabContent).Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, tabWidth, tabHeight));
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have tried adding a couple of `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);` in case it needs more time to recognize the changes, but that is having no effect.  The weirdness with the `PrintDialog()` call is for similar reasons.  Calling it in the usual way makes no difference.

Can anyone either tell me why my printing functionality isn't working without the MessageBox call, or tell me how to simulate a MessageBox call to bluff the program into working?
Many, many TIA

Comment: It's not so easy to reproduce your situation. Could you please append also the xaml code and the snipped where the PrintStatement methode is called. Maybe this would help to reproduce it.

Comment: Maybe all you have to do is calling currentTabContent.Refresh(). Thread.Sleep(250) doesn't help if you call it for the thread doing the measurements and arrangements. Anyway I would rather use a copy of currentTabContent for printing (eg with VisualBrush) then manipulate the original forwards and backwards.

Comment: @rhe1980 ouch have left work for the weekend. will add xaml and calling code Monday

Comment: @LPL I had been thinking it was a race condition, hence the sleep(), but yeah, i'm startign to think that something that Refreshes or Repaints will do it.  Will try your suggestion Monday.

Answer (score 0):

the part you may missing is that `MessageBox.Show();` refreshed the UIElement

so it should be enough if you refesh your UIElement manually with the following code

```
  ui.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));// activates ui.InvalidateMeasure(); 
  ui.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), ui.DesiredSize));                 // activates ui.InvalidateArrange();

  ui.UpdateLayout(); // <-- refreshed your UIElement
```

this works at least in my case

Side note:
you shouldn't call the `ui.Invalidate...` directly because if you aren't change Measure or Arrange because `UpdateLayout()` wouldn't refreshed your `UIElement` AFAIK